# USB Port does not work when all other ports are populated

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-3

I have 4 USB 3 ports in the back of my ASUS z170 motherboard. When I connect devices to all of them one of them stops working.

I have changed the power settings in the control panel and disabled the selective USB suspension.

Is there anything else that I should check. Maybe in the BIOS.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the BIOS up to date?

Comment: Yes it is up to date

Answer (score 2):

The four USB ports probably share one power connection.

It seems like there is not enough power supplied for the four ports to work concurrently.

You may test this by connecting a self-powered device as the fourth one.
If the four ports will work with this configuration, then the problem is indeed power.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. Any solution to this? As mentioned the suspend power is disabled in power settings as well as in the device manager

Comment: Besides changing the electrical connections inside the computer case (unknown if this can help), using a self-powered device as the fourth one is the only one I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a physical issue with the USB ports.

If the motherboard is still under warranty then I would seek help with the manufacturer.